# Runtime exception with Drools(org.drools.util.CompositeClassLoader.clone()Lorg/drools/util/CompositeClassLoader)

Tags: java, drools, nosuchmethoderror

I'm running drools project with Java. The line `KnowledgeBase kbase = readKnowledgeBase();` gives the exception below:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.drools.util.CompositeClassLoader.clone()Lorg/drools/util/CompositeClassLoader;
    at org.drools.compiler.PackageBuilderConfiguration.getClassLoader(PackageBuilderConfiguration.java:322)
    at org.drools.rule.builder.dialect.java.JavaDialectConfiguration.setCompiler(JavaDialectConfiguration.java:91)
    at org.drools.rule.builder.dialect.java.JavaDialectConfiguration.init(JavaDialectConfiguration.java:54)
    at org.drools.compiler.PackageBuilderConfiguration.addDialect(PackageBuilderConfiguration.java:273)
    at org.drools.compiler.PackageBuilderConfiguration.buildDialectConfigurationMap(PackageBuilderConfiguration.java:262)
    at org.drools.compiler.PackageBuilderConfiguration.init(PackageBuilderConfiguration.java:175)
    at org.drools.compiler.PackageBuilderConfiguration.<init>(PackageBuilderConfiguration.java:153)
    at org.drools.compiler.PackageBuilder.<init>(PackageBuilder.java:254)
    at org.drools.compiler.PackageBuilder.<init>(PackageBuilder.java:182)
    at org.drools.builder.impl.KnowledgeBuilderFactoryServiceImpl.newKnowledgeBuilder(KnowledgeBuilderFactoryServiceImpl.java:34)
    at org.drools.builder.KnowledgeBuilderFactory.newKnowledgeBuilder(KnowledgeBuilderFactory.java:47)
    at com.sample.TestExample.readKnowledgeBase(TestExample.java:36)
    at com.sample.TestExample.ProductClassHolder(TestExample.java:56)
    at com.sample.TestExample.main(TestExample.java:30)
```

Comment: Most likely you have a mixture of jars from different Drools releases in your class path. Which version do you think you are using?

Comment: If i am not using multiple version, i facing with class formats. So that is the reason i'm using multiple versions.

Comment: You can't use a mixture of jars from different Drools versions. You'll have to solve your original problem in some other way.

Comment: After deleting multiple version of same jars i facing another issue::

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.drools.util.ChainedProperties.<init>(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/ClassLoader;Z)V
 at org.drools.compiler.PackageBuilderConfiguration.init(PackageBuilderConfiguration.java:161)
 at org.drools.compiler.PackageBuilderConfiguration.<init>(PackageBuilderConfiguration.java:153)
 at org.drools.compiler.PackageBuilder.<init>

Comment: Then it looks like the constructor ChainedProperties(String, Classloader) is not in the version you are using. Do you expect it to be?

Comment: I have the ChainedProperties.class in org.drools.util package

But still it is throwing that erro

Comment: @kanni It means that the same class from another library is getting loaded and overriding the right one at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and struggled with it for a while. In my case the issue was due to the conflict of libraries **drools-api.jar v5.1.1** and **knowledge-api-5.4.0.Final.jar** at runtime. Both of these libraries have class `org.drools.util.CompositeClassLoader` but the one in **drools-api.jar** doesn't have the `clone()` method and this was getting loaded at runtime. I removed **drools-api.jar** and now it is working fine and rules are also getting executed.

Comment: Appears after v5.1 they split it up into two separate standalone knowledge-api and drools-core jars.  I guess...also my hunch is that it's something of a "chance game", sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't, depending on jar loading order somehow...